# Hide a button in a table column based on string in another column

Tags: jquery

I need to remove the form button in the td with `class="center outstanding"` only if `.small` contains the text `XYZ`. I'm using the below code, but it only removes the first instance and stops. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
if ($("div.subtle:contains('XYZ')").length) {
  $('#pay').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="accounts" class="billing">
  <tbody>
    <tr title="Details">
      <td class="tblLeft">
        <div class="small">ABC Company</div>
      </td>
      <td class="center outstanding">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Details">
      <td class="tblLeft">
        <div class="small">XYZ Company</div>
      </td>
      <td class="center outstanding">$161.47<br />
        <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/paythebill.asp" id="payaccountform"><input class="button completeworkflow" type="submit" name="pay" id="pay" value="Pay" title="" /></form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Details">
      <td class="tblLeft">
        <div class="small">XYZ Company</div><br /></td>
      <td class="center outstanding">$0.00<br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Details">
      <td class="tblLeft">
        <div class="small">ABC Company</div>
      </td>
      <td class="center outstanding">$122.88<br />
        <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/paythebill.asp" id="payaccountform"><input class="button completeworkflow" type="submit" name="pay" id="pay" value="Pay" title="" /></form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `:contains` to find the relevant `.small` elements, then traverse the DOM to find the related `form` element within the same `tr` and `hide()` it. Try this:

```js
$('.small:contains("XYZ")').closest('tr').find('form, br').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="accounts" class="billing">
  <tbody>
    <tr title="Details">
      <td class="tblLeft">
        <div class="small">ABC Company</div>
      </td>
      <td class="center outstanding">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Details">
      <td class="tblLeft">
        <div class="small">XYZ Company</div>
      </td>
      <td class="center outstanding">$161.47<br />
        <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/paythebill.asp" id="payaccountform"><input class="button completeworkflow" type="submit" name="pay" id="pay" value="Pay" title="" /></form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Details">
      <td class="tblLeft">
        <div class="small">XYZ Company</div><br /></td>
      <td class="center outstanding">$0.00<br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Details">
      <td class="tblLeft">
        <div class="small">ABC Company</div>
      </td>
      <td class="center outstanding">$122.88<br />
        <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/paythebill.asp" id="payaccountform"><input class="button completeworkflow" type="submit" name="pay" id="pay" value="Pay" title="" /></form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also note that you have duplicated the `pay` and `payaccountform` `id` attributes in your HTML. `id` must be unique. I'd suggest changing them to classes or removing them if unneeded.

Comment: Unfortunately, this page is already created dynamically and I can't modify the code. That's part of the challenge.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see your first response which worked!  Cheers!